# Get the UserControl from DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, telerik, datatemplate, windows-phone-8.1

I have a DataTemplate in which i have simply used a UserControl.

```
DataTemplate x:Key="SampleDataTemplate">
        <controls1:UserControl1>

        </controls1:UserControl1>
</DataTemplate>
```

This DataTemplate is used in `TransitionControl.ContentTemplate` Now I want the UserControl1 Object in the c# CodeBehind.

Something Like this

`TransitionControl.ContentTemplate this DataTemplate will give me UserControl1 object.`

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to do that ... So I'm not sure there is an easy way to do it. Why do you need to get the instance of your UserControl ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Miiite you just asked the wrong question :). It is something like that i have to call a method in this control say a custom backpress in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`VisualTreeHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper)'s `GetChildrenCount` and `GetChild` methods to get to the control that you need. Here's a method that will help (tweak it if necessary):

```
private List<T> FindChildren<T>(DependencyObject startNode, List<T> results = null) where T : DependencyObject {
    if (results == null) results = new List<T>();

    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(startNode);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        DependencyObject current = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(startNode, i);
        if ((current.GetType()).Equals(typeof(T)) || (current.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)))) {
            T realType = (T)current;
            results.Add(realType);
        }
        FindChildren<T>(current, results);
    }

    return results;
}
```

So, all you need to do is call `FindChildren<UserControl1>(MyTransitionControlInstance)` and you'll get get the instance of the UserControl1 control (well, all of the instances, if there are more).

P.S. It really is a good idea to tweak the method to just look for one element, and not for all of them, if you need just one which seems to be the case.